# C# & Design Patterns - need an elegant solution for a common issue

Tags: c#, design-patterns, polymorphism, adapter

I have 2 projects : The first project is a structure project which i read from an xml file.
This project is used in other solutions
The second project(1 of the other solutions) work on the structure project with foreach running on components list:

```
namespace FriendProject.Workers
{
    public class Worker
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (Component component in ComponentList)
            {
                DoWork(component);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Today the DoWork method does the following:

```
public void DoWork(Component component)
{
   // Doing work on component properties
   // Zip component files with open source Zipper
   if (component is DBComponent)
   {
      // work on DBComponent properties
    }
}
```

Now if you are familiar with design patterns then you can see that there is an injection point here and the following should be done :

```
public class Component
    {
        public virtual void DoWork()
        {
            // Do work
        }
    }

    public class DBComponent : Component
    {
        public override void DoWork()
        {
            base.DoWork();
            // injection point - work on DBComponent properties
        }
    }

    public class Operator
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (Component component in ComponentList)
            {
                component.DoWork();
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the project which holds the Component and DBComponent is a structure project which is used in other solutions and with other projects and I need to add the open source Zip dll to the project and it becomes more tightly coupled to the current project("FriendProject") and less usable. Not to talk about that the other projects will never use these methods(DoWork in Component and DBComponent)

Is there a better solution without changing much the design? Should I add an adpater?
If so please provide and example.
Thanks to all

**Edit: Short Question**
2 projects :
One is a manager project which acts on the second project.
Second is a structure project(read data from xml) which is reused with other projects.
I want to add methods and refernces(since of polymorphism) in the structure project(second project). However it feels wrong since the other projects that uses it will never use those methods and the added references.
Is there a better solution for how to do it?

**Edit :**
Removed the structure project code the shorten the question. this code was irrelavent since its classes(Component and DBComponent) appear next.

Comment: Is there a short version of your question? I am not sure I got the important point between all those text and code.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I edited the quesion with a short question. However the details that I added above should be considered for the full picture. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy (and with three different GOF design patterns).

Since we can't do anything with the components, we'll have to use the bridge pattern.

Let's define handlers:

```
public interface IHandlerOf<T> where T : Component
{
    void DoWork(T component);
}
```

So now we can create a handler type for each component type that we want to handle. A DB component handler would look like this:

```
public class DbComponentHandler : IHandlerOf<DbComponent>
{
    public void DoWork(DbComponent component)
    {
        // do db specific information here
    }
}
```

But since we don't really want to keep track of all handlers we'll want to create a class that does it for us. We ultimately want to invoke the code just as in your example:

```
foreach (Component component in ComponentList)
{
    handler.DoWork(component);
}
```

But let's make it a bit cooler:

```
//maps handlers to components
var service = new ComponentService();

// register all handlers in the current assembly
service.Register(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

// fake a component
var dbComponent = new DbComponent();

// the cool part, the invoker doesn't have to know
// about the handlers = facade pattern
service.Invoke(dbComponent);
```

The service with makes it possible looks like this:

```
public class ComponentService
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, IHandlerInvoker> _handlers = new Dictionary<Type, IHandlerInvoker>();

    public void Register(Assembly assembly)
    {
        foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes())
        {
            if (type.IsInterface)
                continue;

            foreach (var interfaceType in type.GetInterfaces())
            {
                if (!interfaceType.IsGenericType || interfaceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(IHandlerOf<>))
                    continue;

                var componentType = interfaceType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                var method = instance.GetType().GetMethod("DoWork", new[] { componentType });

                _handlers[componentType] = new ReflectionInvoker(instance, method);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Register<T>(IHandlerOf<T> handler) where T : Component
    {
        _handlers[typeof (T)] = new DirectInvoker<T>(handler);
    }

    #region Nested type: DirectInvoker

    private class DirectInvoker<T> : IHandlerInvoker where T : Component
    {
        private readonly IHandlerOf<T> _handler;

        public DirectInvoker(IHandlerOf<T> handler)
        {
            _handler = handler;
        }

        #region IHandlerInvoker Members

        public void Invoke(Component component)
        {
            _handler.DoWork((T) component);
        }

        #endregion
    }

    #endregion

    #region Nested type: IHandlerInvoker

    private interface IHandlerInvoker
    {
        void Invoke(Component component);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Nested type: ReflectionInvoker

    private class ReflectionInvoker : IHandlerInvoker
    {
        private readonly object _instance;
        private readonly MethodInfo _method;

        public ReflectionInvoker(object instance, MethodInfo method)
        {
            _instance = instance;
            _method = method;
        }

        #region IHandlerInvoker Members

        public void Invoke(Component component)
        {
            _method.Invoke(_instance, new object[] {component});
        }

        #endregion
    }

    #endregion

    public void Invoke(Component component)
    {
        IHandlerInvoker invoker;
        if (!_handlers.TryGetValue(component.GetType(), out invoker))
            throw new NotSupportedException("Failed to find a handler for " + component.GetType());

        invoker.Invoke(component);
    }
}
```

Do note that the interface (`IHandlerOf<T>`) is generic which means that we can't store it directly in a Dictionary. Hence we use the Adapter pattern to store all handlers.

---

Full example:

```
public interface IHandlerOf<in T> where T : Component
{
    void DoWork(T component);
}


public class ComponentService
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, IHandlerInvoker> _handlers = new Dictionary<Type, IHandlerInvoker>();

    public void Register(Assembly assembly)
    {
        foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes())
        {
            if (type.IsInterface)
                continue;

            foreach (var interfaceType in type.GetInterfaces())
            {
                if (!interfaceType.IsGenericType || interfaceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(IHandlerOf<>))
                    continue;

                var componentType = interfaceType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                var method = instance.GetType().GetMethod("DoWork", new[] { componentType });

                _handlers[componentType] = new ReflectionInvoker(instance, method);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Register<T>(IHandlerOf<T> handler) where T : Component
    {
        _handlers[typeof (T)] = new DirectInvoker<T>(handler);
    }

    #region Nested type: DirectInvoker

    private class DirectInvoker<T> : IHandlerInvoker where T : Component
    {
        private readonly IHandlerOf<T> _handler;

        public DirectInvoker(IHandlerOf<T> handler)
        {
            _handler = handler;
        }

        #region IHandlerInvoker Members

        public void Invoke(Component component)
        {
            _handler.DoWork((T) component);
        }

        #endregion
    }

    #endregion

    #region Nested type: IHandlerInvoker

    private interface IHandlerInvoker
    {
        void Invoke(Component component);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Nested type: ReflectionInvoker

    private class ReflectionInvoker : IHandlerInvoker
    {
        private readonly object _instance;
        private readonly MethodInfo _method;

        public ReflectionInvoker(object instance, MethodInfo method)
        {
            _instance = instance;
            _method = method;
        }

        #region IHandlerInvoker Members

        public void Invoke(Component component)
        {
            _method.Invoke(_instance, new object[] {component});
        }

        #endregion
    }

    #endregion

    public void Invoke(Component component)
    {
        IHandlerInvoker invoker;
        if (!_handlers.TryGetValue(component.GetType(), out invoker))
            throw new NotSupportedException("Failed to find a handler for " + component.GetType());

        invoker.Invoke(component);
    }
}

public class DbComponent : Component
{
}

public class DbComponentHandler : IHandlerOf<DbComponent>
{
    public void DoWork(DbComponent component)
    {
        // do db specific information here
        Console.WriteLine("some work done!");
    }
}


internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var service = new ComponentService();
        service.Register(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        var dbComponent = new DbComponent();
        service.Invoke(dbComponent);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure you want to split data structure and data operations, create separate worker class.

```
public interface IWorker
{
    void DoWork();
}

public abstract Worker<T>: IWorker where T: Component
{
     private T _component;
     protected Worker(T component) {_component = component;}
     public abstract void DoWork();
}

public class DbWorker: Worker<DbComponent>
{
     public DbWorker(DbComponent component): base(component) {}
     public override DoWork() {...}
}
```

and implement some factory to create specific workers from specific components.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered having `Operator` and `Component` packaged together, and `DBComponent` in a second project, as for the other projecs of the solution ? Then, you could use a light container such as Spring.net to configure your `.exe` and load the relevant assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

It is the right thing to give your Component behaviours instead of having the worker class manipulating its properties.

If you don't want other project to see the doWork method, hide it behind an public interface and create an adapter from the public interface to your internal one.

```
public interface ComponentPublic {
    void sharedMethod();
}

public class ComponentPublicAdapter implement ComponentPublic {
    private Component component;
    void sharedMethod() {
        // Do something, may be call doWork()
    }
}
```

Package the ComponentPublic interface in a different project/namespace, therefore other projects may interact with it without knowing the internal interface. Use a dependency injection framework or reflection to instantiate the adapter and Components.